# Text flow using boostrap columns "like a newspaper "

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am working on a WP project. I have been trying to  have a nice text flow between  columns using bootstrap frame work.

I need the same story flowing among diverse columns what apparently seems to be called as "like newspapers".  I have  found some  examples using  just the multi column in css  but I would prefer to just do it in  bootstrap.

I assume that  the each colum must have a  height so there is a point where the  story breaks to the other column .

Here is an example of my  code :

```
 <div class=' col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>  
     <?php get_template_part ('template-parts/content/content', 'image');?>
 </div>
 <article  class=' col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>  
     <?php get_template_part ('template-parts/content/content', 'pack');?>
 </article>
 <article class=' col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>  
 </article>                   

 <?php
```

Thanks in advance for   all  your help and orientation .

Comment: Please add the image.

Comment: Why not carry on using CSS columns? It's what it was made for. Slicing and moving content between HTML columns is more difficult and has a less desired result. You'll lose semantic value and the accessibility will be worse. You'll also have the risk of those columns becoming very unbalanced.

Comment: Thanks for the  Adam, Well  I guess  I  ll opt  to do the css  way  . I thought it  would be more logic  to   use bootstrap columns . Maybe, more practical.  Otherwise it should be called table,  because there is not  text flow connection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question has a pure Bootstrap solution - however, you can design multi-column looks with pure CSS as explained here: [Bootstrap Writing In Columns (like a newspaper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871693/bootstrap-writing-in-columns-like-a-newspaper).